How to subscribe to TopicMessageQuery (Hedera SDK) without a Client instance?
In a DApp, using a Hedera-native wallet (e.g. Hashpack or Blade), I need to subscribe to a TopicMessageQuery. The standard way to do this on a server would be:
const subscription = new TopicMessageQuery()
    .setTopicId(topicId)
    .subscribe(client, (msg) => { /* do something with msg */ });

where TopicMessageQuery and Client are imported from @hashgraph/sdk, and client is an instance of Client.
However, in a front-end browser app, it isn't proper to have a Client instance, as that would mean exposing the private key of a Hedera account (which is obviously a security problem). Instead within the DApp, there would only be instances of Signer objects (accessible via the Hashpack/ Blade browser extensions' injections into the window object). These do not have the same API as Client, and thus cannot be used as the first parameter value in a TopicMessageQuery#subscribe function invocation.
Is it possible to invoke TopicMessageQuery#subscribe without an instance of Client and somehow use an instance of Signer (or something else) instead? If so, how?

Attempted Solutions
Attempt 1
Looking at the implementation for
TopicMessageQuery#subscribe,
the only use of the Client instance is this:
        client._mirrorNetwork
            .getNextMirrorNode()
            .getChannel()
            .makeServerStreamRequest(...);

This appears to indicate that the actual "signer" part of the Client instance is not necessary,
and what is really needed is data about which Hedera network it is connected to,
and thereby able to work out which Hedera Mirror Nodes to connect to.
To test this hypothesis, I created a "dummy" Client instance,
by using a randomly generated private key,
a fake account ID,
and with the Testnet default configuration.
const accountId = '0.0.12345';
const privateKey = PrivateKey. generateED25519();
const dummyClient = Client.forTestnet().setOperator(accountId, privateKey);

Subsequently, use it like so:
const subscription = new TopicMessageQuery()
    .setTopicId(topicId)
    .subscribe(dummyClient, callback);

However, that throws an error immediately within the Hedera SDK's
TopicMessageQuery#subscribe implementation,
because client._mirrorNetwork.getNextMirrorNode() is undefined.
This is despite dummyClient has been instantiated
using Client.forTestnet().
Attempt 2
Tried the same as above, but instead of using a "dummy" Client instance, used a real one:
const accountId = '0.0.1521'; // actual account on Hedera Testnet
const privateKey = '302e02...'; // actual private key for 0.0.1521
const dummyClient = Client.forTestnet().setOperator(accountId, privateKey);

Subsequently, use it like so (same as before):
const subscription = new TopicMessageQuery()
    .setTopicId(topicId)
    .subscribe(dummyClient, callback);

However, that results in the same error (where client._mirrorNetwork.getNextMirrorNode() is undefined).
Therefore this error seems to be caused by something other than whether a real account is used.
There's a tiny clue from the console.log output, which is that the client is not a Client object but rather a WebClient object:

Perhaps the WebClient implementations differs from the Client implementation in terms of how client._mirrorNetwork.getNextMirrorNode() behaves?
Attempt 3
Noticed that WebClient#setMirrorNetwork
and NodeClient#setMirrorNetwork
have different implementations.
So I manually called Client#setMirrorNetwork with the Hedera Testnet Mirror Node API endpoint.
const accountId = '0.0.1521'; // actual account on Hedera Testnet
const privateKey = '302e02...'; // actual private key for 0.0.1521
const dummyClient = Client.forTestnet().setOperator(accountId, privateKey);
dummyClient.setMirrorNetwork(['testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com:443']);

Subsequently, use it like so (same as before):
const subscription = new TopicMessageQuery()
    .setTopicId(topicId)
    .subscribe(dummyClient, callback);

This does not result in the same error as before, as  client._mirrorNetwork.getNextMirrorNode() is now defined.

Therefore, was hopeful that the subscription would work this time, however, there was a different error:
Error: mirror support is not supported in browsers
    at MirrorNode._channelInitFunction (WebClient.js:226:1)
    at MirrorNode.getChannel (ManagedNode.js:198:1)
    at TopicMessageQuery._makeServerStreamRequest (TopicMessageQuery.js:373:1)
    at TopicMessageQuery.subscribe (TopicMessageQuery.js:336:1)
    at skillSubscribe (skill-subscribe.js:72:6)


Refs

Documentation for hashconnect, the Hashpack SDK.

https://github.com/Hashpack/hashconnect/blob/main/README.md#sending-requests


Code examples for HCS create/update/delete topic, HCS submit, but not HCS subscribe.

https://github.com/Hashpack/hashconnect/tree/main/example/dapp/src/app/components/
see the ones with the hcs- prefix, e.g.: https://github.com/Hashpack/hashconnect/tree/main/example/dapp/src/app/components/hcs-create-topic


Hedera SDK documentation for TopicMessageQuery#subscribe

https://hashgraph.github.io/hedera-sdk-js/classes/index.TopicMessageQuery.html#subscribe



